# My Express server is sending HTML instead of JSON when in production on vercel but it works on localhost in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, vercel

Title basically says it all, I'm making an app for students to rate their teachers but res.json() is sending a html file with just the nav bar, it's weird because when I run the server on my Macbook it works and send json.

Here's my backend index.js

```
console.clear();

const express = require('express');
const db = require('./config/db');
const cors = require('cors');
const cluster = require('cluster');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const path = require('path');

require('colors');
require('dotenv').config();

app = express();

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log('Node NOT Exiting...');
});

// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

db.connectDb();

app.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) =>
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico')
);

app.use('/api/teachers', require('./routes/teacherRoutes'));
app.use('/api/ratings', require('./routes/ratingRoutes'));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Static folder
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));

  // Handle SPA
  app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
}
console.log(__dirname);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`.dim.bold);
});
```

the "/favicon.ico" works even in Vercel, the lines to handle the frontend work(I think) yet the "/api/teachers" and the other ones don't work heres how the "/api/teachers" work - also keep in mind I'm focusing on the teacher endpoint but none of them work:

```
//get all teachers
const get = async (req, res) => {
  res.json(await Teacher.find());
};
const post = async (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.name) {
    if ((await Teacher.exists({ name: req.body.name })) == null) {
      res.json(await Teacher.create({ name: req.body.name }));
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({
        message:
          'The teacher you are trying to add is already in the database.',
      });
    }
  } else {
    res
      .status(400)
      .json({ message: 'Please add a teacher name to your request' });
  }
};
module.exports = {
  get,
  post,
};
```

here's some of my vercel config:

```
    "require": "@vercel/static-build",
      "requirePath": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vercel/node_modules/@vercel/static-build/dist/index",
      "apiVersion": 2,
      "src": "package.json",
      "use": "@vercel/static-build",
      "config": {
        "zeroConfig": true,
        "framework": "vue",
        "installCommand": "npm install",
        "buildCommand": "npm run build",
        "outputDirectory": "/backend/public"
      }
```

Comment: "some of my vercel config" - it's specific to Vercel and it's unknown what you do to deploy it. You're supposed to run Express server in prod but there's no sign you do this